# One of two similar WP Query is very slow

Tags: wp-query, mysql

I have two WP Query are very similar. one is fast and another is very very slow. I have already test two query via mysql directly.

the fast one:
`SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_posts.post_date >= '2019-09-04 21:45:00' )
AND ( ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcm_home_club'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '37358' ) 
OR ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcm_away_club'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '37358' ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpcm_match'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC
LIMIT 0, 500`

and the slow one below:

`SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_posts.post_date < '2019-09-04 21:45:00' )
AND ( ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcm_home_club'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '37358' ) 
OR ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcm_away_club'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '37358' ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpcm_match'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 1`

I'm curious that why another is so slow?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely there are very few rows WHERE
AND ( wp_posts.post_date >= '2019-09-04 21:45:00' )
there are likely many thousands of rows WHERE
AND ( wp_posts.post_date < '2019-09-04 21:45:00' )
and a table scan is required.  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE remainder of query for each and examine results carefully.  Post the TEXT RESULTS of EACH EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE remainder of your query for our assistance in understanding what is going on.

Comment: @cloudinstone Have you made any progress?  If the comment was helpful, please upvote and possibly Accept.